# How do i use a script in another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so, my code;

Script one;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mousePosTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 mousePos;
    public void Update()
    {
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Debug.Log(mousePos);
    }

}
```

and script two;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(// mouse position);
    }
}
```

the code currently is pretty bare-bones, but I will fix that. so what I want to do is; I want to access the vector2 mousePos variable in script2, so that I can move the player based on the mouse position.

Comment: Why do you need two objects for that instead of doing both in the player class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a reference on your `Player` script to your `MousePosTrackerScript` and use it.
One recommendation, use [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) on your class names.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MouseousePosTracker posTracker = null; //attach it from your Editor or via script

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(posTracker.mousePos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in your 2nd script, always make sure your script has first letter in caps.

EDIT: if you do not want to give reference (drag&drop) in editor, use the below example. If you want it to be simpler without providing reference in the script, use Lotan's solution.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MousePosTracker mouse;
    
    void Start()
    {
        mouse = (MousePosTracker) GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(MousePosTracker));
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(mouse.mousePos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use the Find method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MousePosTracker mousePosTracker;
    
    void Start(){
       mousePosTracker = GameObject.Find("gameobject name which has the MousePosTrackerScript").GetComponent<MousePosTracker>()
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(mousePosTracker.mousePos);
    }
}
```

If the gameobject has a tag you can use the FindWithTag method too.